# 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression when waiting for a promise based function

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to await for a promise based function to execute, but in vs code it is showing that 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.

Await is working perfectly of mongoose queries in nested function

Function

```
addRequest: async (booking) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        bookingRequests.push(booking);
        const message = "Pushed Successfully in Topic";
        resolve(message);
    });
}
```

Await Call

```
if(...){...}
else{
    if(...){...}
    else{
        ...
        const msg = await addRequest(booking)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `async` function always returns a promise, so you don't need to explicitly create one yourself in `addRequest` function and unless `bookingRequests.push` is an async operation, there's nothing asynchronous about the code in `addRequest` function, so not sure why you are using an async function.

Comment: async/await only matters for calling async functions. Where are you calling one in your `addRequest`?

Comment: Is `bookingRequests.push` an asynchronous operation?

Comment: I understand your point, there is no point in using promise here.